# this context bug in javascript - why doesn't this trigger a bug?

Tags: javascript

I thought this was suppose to trigger a bug when calling a function from within a function using the keyword this.  Running Chrome 37.0

```
S = function () {
    this.x = "test";
    this.test1 = function () {
        console.log("test1");
        this.test2();
    };
    this.test2 = function () {
        console.log(this); // output is s object, thought 'this' suppose to be global?
        console.log("test2");
    };
};
s = new S();
s.test1();
```

Edit:

I mixed it up with this code:

```
   s = function () {
            console.log(this);
            var t = function () {

                console.log(this);
            };
           t();


    };
  x = new s();
```

Comment: Bug? Which bug? Why do you think it should "trigger a bug"?

Comment: 'this' being changed to global object instead of the actual object.

Comment: If you call `this.test2()` (as a method!), why would the context become the global object?

Comment: Nothing about "Functions within functions" implicitly triggers a change to `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a function as part of an expression where you get the function reference from an object property calls the function with `this` set to the object you got the property from.

So your code:

```
s.test1();
```

...will call `test1` setting `this` equal to the object referenced by `s`, because the call is part of an expression getting the `test1` function reference from a property on the object `s` refers to.

Then in `test1`, when you do:

```
this.test2();
```

...it calls `test2` setting `this` equal to the object referenced by `this`, because the call is part of an expression getting the `test2` function reference from a property on the object `this` refers to.

Where you'd run into a problem with `this` not being set correctly would be if you *didn't* call `test1` or `test2` via an object property, like this:

```
var f = s.test1;
f();
```

Then, within the call to `test1`, `this` would be the global object (in loose mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode). The same sort of thing happens when passing a function as an argument:

```
foo(s.test1);
```

If `foo` calls the function its first argument relates to, we get the same thing (`this` = global object or `undefined`).

Since you're not doing that, though, that doesn't happen.

The key thing here is *how the function is called*, not where it's defined (inside another function or not).

---

More on `this` in [*How Does The `this` Keyword Work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?lq=1) here on SO, and in [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) on my blog.